# Running neural network pybrain

Tags: python, scipy, neural-network, pybrain

I want to create neural network and install scipy and PyBrain for it. 
On file i write:

```
from pybrain.tools.shortcuts import buildNetwork
net=buildNetwork(4,2,1)
```

and when i run that file, an error occured

```
from scipy.linalq import inv,det, svd, logm, expm2
ImportError: cannot import name expm2
```

Can you advise something?

Comment: Maybe an outdated scipy version?

Comment: @FerdinandBeyer the version of scipy is 1.0.0rc1

Comment: Looks like `expm2` has been deprecated since scipy 0.13. I did not find any evidence quickly, but it can well be removed in the version you are using. So your scipy version might be too new for your pybrain version. :)
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/release.0.13.0.html#deprecated-features

Answer (score 7):

Scipy latest version doesn't contain `scipy.linalg.expm2`. Instead, it has `scipy.linalg._expm_frechet`. So open up that .py file in Pybrain `(pybrain.tools.functions)` and replace the line `from scipy.linalg import inv, det, svd, logm, expm2` with `from scipy.linalg import inv, det, svd, logm, _expm_frechet` and it should solve your problem.

Comment: as of 2019-01-26 still works and is needed even if directly installing version 0.3.3

Answer (score 0):

This error message is basically saying:

`expm2 isn't installed. i.e. Your scipy version hasn't got expm2 or something went wrong during the installation.`

Try reinstalling `scipy`, that should do it.

Comment: It did not help

Answer (score 0):

The function `scipy.linalg.expm2` used by PyBrain has been deprecated since v.0.13 and [has been removed](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/releases) in v.1.0.0 (not yet released):

> The deprecated functions `expm2` and `expm3` have been removed from
>   `scipy.linalg`.

(In section "Backwards incompatible changes")

As it seems that PyBrain has not been updated yet, you need to fall back to a Scipy version that still contains this function, such as the last release v.0.19.1.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. I don't know if it is still relevant, but for me the error dissapeared when I changed expm2 to expm.

Answer (score 0):

Just to make things easier for everyone out there trying this solution:

1. in the python console after installing the pybrain library, type **pybrain.tools.functions** as the attached figure is showing up
2. after the word "from" between simple quotes is your file path for the .py functions file used as show on the figure
   [File path shown on the python console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I0xls.png)

3. open it up and press **CTRL + F** to search for the **expm2** reference in the import statement amongst the first lines of code in the file
4. on the import statement **for expm2**, replace **expm2** for **_expm_frechet** as shown on the figure
   [Replacement of **expm2** for **_exp_frechet**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n36H2.png)

5. now, try running your code again and jupyter lab should work with the pybrain library

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem u can do it:
Find the file "functions.py" in
"C:\Users<user-name>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Lib\site-packages\pybrain\tools"

Find this command "from scipy.linalg import", and then change "expm2" to "expm", do it in this function too "def sqrtm(M)":

"expm2(0.5 * logm(M)" to "expm(0.5 * logm(M)".